# vis.js add a small circle inside a box node

Tags: javascript, canvas, vis.js, chap-links-library

Using Vis.js, I'm trying to create a network graph that displays a collection of nodes. Each node is box shaped with some text inside it. I want to add a small colored circle besides the text that will change it's color depends on the data provided.

Is such functionality even possible in Vis, if so, how could I achieve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to add something like a dot *inside* the box, you can only display plain text.

You can give the box and text itself a custom color, or you can give the nodes a shape `dot` (text is then displayed below the nodes), and give the node a specific color.

Example: [http://visjs.org/examples/network/06_groups.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20150317041010/https://visjs.org/examples/network/06_groups.html)

Comment: In the end I've turned to D3.js, and just concatenated a small rectangular HTML template to a connecting line and added a small circle shape on top of it.

Comment: how did you use a rectangular html template as a node in D3.js?